# What is the best way to store an array for a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

I have the following **working** code on my background.js:

```
var targetList = ["youtube.com", "vimeo.com"];  

for (var i = 0, n = targetList.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (sender.tab.url.indexOf(targetList[i]) != -1) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Currently `targetList` is only two references but I need to load a lot more. Also, I need to use it twice on my backgound.js.

What is the best way to store the `targetList` seperatly and reference to it when needed? Any change necessary in my manifest.json?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Also, you can use [for(of)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Goal is to store the array more efficiently, [K3N](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1693593/k3n) feedback is what I needed. `for(of)` works great and code is more neat, thanks! can't use `array.includes()` since then I'd have to write the whole URLs on my array ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For frequent use just use memory (or post it to a background page, to send back when needed). For more permanent use you can store in local storage for example:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"targetList": targetList});
```

then retrieve it:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("targetList", callback);

function callback(result) {
  targetList = result.targetList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @K3N

Comment: This has limits I tried to set 120 objects but only 75 objects got saved any idea why? i think chrome storage is limited